# docx to latex with references

Tags: word-to-latex

So I might be in a bit of a pickle here. I'm about to finish my final thesis and for this I will have to put several of my papers into one document. My papers are written in MS Word as .docx and the thesis template is in LaTeX.

I have found pandoc as a fairly good tool to convert the documents. However, one major issue is that the references are not exported as such - pandoc transform them into simple text. The problem is that for my thesis there needs to be only one reference section at the end, which summerizes all the references from the single papers.

Is there a way I can use pandoc (or any other tool) to transform the docx references into latex references?

Thanks!

Comment: How many separate reference sections do you have?  Would it be feasible to manually move them in the converted TeX code?  (The other option is to make your Word doc match the thesis template, which may or may not be easier, depending on the template and how strict your university is.)

Comment: What format are the references in? Did you use a tool to build bibliographies, or just write them by hand? If some tool and database, search for that. If by hand, however...

Comment: It's like several hundred references, so I won't be really able to do it manually. 

I did use Mendeley to add the references automatically to word. Unfortunately, I don't quite find anything that would help me solve my problem with that? (or more likely I don't understand it...)